# Newly Published Razor Page App Will Not Run/Open in Browser

Tags: asp.net, configuration, null, razor-pages, publish

I have my web app completed and want to publish it. Let me say upfront that it is entirely probable that I am doing something wrong or have made incorrect choices in my publish profile. This is my very first app!

It runs fine with no errors within Visual Studio. It does have a couple of warnings about nulls - would that keep it from publishing? I have eliminated all of them but a couple (which I am not sure how to get rid of at this point - Dereference of a possibly null reference) and as it is a historical info 'view only' app, with no data being able to be modified, is that really an issue?

When I publish, I am publishing to a network folder. The publish succeds, but when I click the application file in the folder, it opens a command prompt window and runs a few lines of code and then stops. No browser opens. I never view the app itself.

Here is what was in the command prompt window:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: S:\Visual Studio Projects\Healthy Shots\
```

My Publishing profile choices are:

- Configuration: Release
- Target Framework: net6.0
- Deployment Method: Self-contained
- Target Runtime: win-x86

File Publish Options:

- Produce single file
- Delete all existing files prior to publish

Databases:
Default Connection with 'Use this connection string at runtime' checked. Below that shows the connection string that is in my app.

Entity Framework Migrations (nothing here)

Any assistance would be much appreciated. Thank you! Please let me know if you require additional information.

Comment: Instead of double clicking to launch the app, try this: open up a command prompt, navigate to the folder that contains your app, and launch the exe from there. This time do you see some information right before the app exits that helps you?

Comment: 'S:\Visual Studio Projects\H' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: This doesn't really help me at the level of skills that I have unfortunately. The file type itself says 'application' in the folder that I published it to.

Comment: Did you properly launch your command prompt and change directories to the location that you published your app to?

Comment: As far as I know I did. I just put "s:the complete path.exe" and hit enter.

Comment: Why did you put s: in front of it? What you need to do is open up a command prompt, enter the command to change to the directory that hosts your app (such as `cd "S:\Visual Studio Projects\Healthy Shots\"` and then press enter) and then run your app by typing in the name of the executable and pressing enter.

Comment: OK. Tried a few more times. Finally, it didn't do the "internal or external, etc" message. This time is opened another command prompt window with basicall the same info messages as above EXCEPT this time the Content root path was incorrect. This time is was trying to look under my user ID on another drive. Not sure how it got that? The content root path above was correct.

Answer (score 0):

According to the output, the application has launched successfully and is running. If you want to see it in a browser, you need to launch that yourself and navigate to `https://localhost:5001`. Web apps do not launch browsers themselves. It would make no sense for them to do so as they typically execute on a web server which might not even have a browser installed on it. Your IDE might launch a browser when you press F5 or Ctrl+F5 to run the app locally, but that is not the same thing.

Comment: I did not understand that. Thank you for the explanation. I clicked the application file, let it open the command prompt window and spiel its few lines, then opened my browser at the local host link and, as you said, the app was there. 

My question that arises from this is: How do end users access this app then? Do they have to follow the same process? I would think they would have only one link to click and the app should open on their default browser? How do you create this (what I would consider) expected behavior?

Thanks so much for your assistance!

Comment: It's a web application. You deploy it to a publicly facing web server. It is not intended to be run directly by users. They will use a browser to access  the application, just like you did with Stackoverflow.